# Change leaf values of a tree to ordered sequence while preserving the tree's structure

Tags: haskell, tree, tree-traversal

Given is a recursive tree structure

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Tree deriving Show
```

I would like to normalize it in a way that preserves the tree's structure, but makes the integers at the leaves sequential in depths-first order. How can I achieve this? My current setup code looks as follows:

```
myTree = Node (Leaf 3) (Node (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2))

myTree' = normalize myTree

-- preserve tree structure, but make Ints sequential in depths-first traversal
normalize :: Tree -> Tree
normalize = id -- todo: implement

main = do
    print myTree  -- prints      : Node (Leaf 3) (Node (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2))
    print myTree' -- should print: Node (Leaf 1) (Node (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using monads, you can write one function mapping trees carrying certain state

```
mapLRS :: (s -> Int -> (s, Int)) -> s -> Tree -> (Tree, s)
mapLRS f s (Leaf x  ) =
    let (s', x') = f s x
    in  (Leaf x', s')                  -- the mapped leaf and the new state
mapLRS f s (Node l r) =
    let (l', s' ) = mapLRS f s  l      -- the mapped left branch and the new state
        (r', s'') = mapLRS f s' r      -- the mapped right branch and the new state
    in  (Node l' r', s'')
```

now

```
normalize :: Tree -> Tree
normalize = fst . mapWithStateLeftRight (\s _ -> (s + 1, s)) 1
```

Using monads could be more readable (`f` is not the same for simplicity using `state`)

```
import Control.Monad.State

mapLRS :: (s -> (Int, s)) -> Tree -> State s Tree
mapLRS f (Leaf   x) = Leaf <$> state f
mapLRS f (Node l r) = Node <$> mapLRS f l <*> mapLRS f r

normalize :: Tree -> Tree
normalize tree = evalState (mapLRS (\s -> (s, s + 1)) tree) 1
```

Comment: [Works great](http://ideone.com/bfO62J) (slightly simplified state function). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to record the current label in a state monad:

```
import Control.Monad.State

data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Tree deriving (Show)

normalize :: Tree -> Tree
normalize t = evalState (go t) 1 where

  go :: Tree -> State Int Tree
  go (Leaf _)   = Leaf <$> (get <* modify (+1))
  go (Node l r) = Node <$> go l <*> go r
```

This solution initializes the state to `1`, then traverses the tree and on each encountered `Leaf` it puts the current label in the returned `Leaf` and increments the label.

Alternatively, we can derive the `Traversable` instance for `Tree`:

```
{-# language DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}

import Control.Monad.State

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

normalize :: Tree a -> Tree Int
normalize = (`evalState` 1) . traverse (\_ -> get <* modify (+1))
```

This works the same way, but that note that it relies on the fact that the derived `Traversable` instance has the right traversal order. Of course, if we wanted some other order then we would have to write our own traversals.